# get X and Y position of string character written in div or where it is break

Tags: javascript, html

I want X and Y coordinates of string character written in div tag or position where it is break or from which character it is break in small size div tag.

I have a `<div>` element with a `contenteditable` attribute like `<textarea>` with css attribute word-wrap:break word. I want to know , from which letter text goes to next line (without new line , for constant text). So can i get the letter where y position of the letter is changed ? so that i can add new line after that letter to draw text with canvas.

Comment: Can you give some sort of example?? what actually you want and your desire result

Comment: I don't know a direct solution but... if you're using a mono space font you can fairly get the coordinates by the char index in the whole string, because mono fonts have the same width height for every letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a font that has a common width and height for each letter, say `monospace` at 16px (which I just worked to calculate), if you compare this to the width of your `div`, you may use something like this:

---

```
HTML:

<div id="input" contenteditable="true" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; font-size: 16px; font-family: monospace; line-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; border: 1px solid #bbbbbb">
  Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text.
</div>
```

---

```
JavaScript:

var input = document.getElementById("input");

function getXandY(index) {
    var x = 0, y = 0;

    var length = input.innerHTML.substring(0, index).length; // Get length between beginning of string and chosen index

    x = (length % 10); // Get letter index on line

    if(length < 100) {
        y = Math.floor(length / 10);  
    } else {
        y = length / 100;   
    }

    // Only works for chars less than 1000;

    return "X: " + x + " Y: " + y;
}

alert(getXandY(23));
```

---

Also, see this **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mkv60e5g/1/)**.
Should work, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the range object over substrings of the text node to collect boundingRects:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect